# Rails NOT IN query and regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have array of strings:

```
a = ['*@foo.com', '*@bar.com', '*@baz.com']
```

I would like to query my model so I will get all the records where email isn't in any of above domains.

I could do:

```
Model.where.not(email: a)
```

If the list would be a list of strings but the list is more of a regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your database adapter. You will probably be able to use raw SQL to write this type of query. For example in postgres you could do:

```
Model.where("email NOT SIMILAR TO '%@foo.com'")
```

I'm not saying thats exactly how you should be doing it but it's worth looking up your database's query language and see if anything matches your needs.

In your example you would have to join together your matchers as a single string and interpolate it into the query.

```
a = ['%@foo.com', '%@bar.com', '%@baz.com']

Model.where("email NOT SIMILAR TO ?", a.join("|"))
```

Comment: its Postgres and i am aware of NOT LIKE notation - i just have array of strings so I can't simply stick it inside **'%@foo.com'**.

Comment: Postgres lets you use multiple arguments to a like using the `|` operator, so just interpolate a.join('|') and make sure your patterns are in postgres format.

Comment: After a little bit of reading it looks like `similar to` is more what you're looking for. i've updated my answer with an example

Comment: nice thank you mate. LIKE/NOT didn't work but SIMILAR TO is doing a job. I need to read a bit about it. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
a = ['%@foo.com', '%@bar.com', '%@baz.com']
Model.where.not("email like ?",a.join("|"))
```

Replace `*` to `%` in array.

Comment: Note that if you're using PostgreSQL and have mixed cases in your data, you should use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE`